# Laravel / Stripe API - undefined method sources()

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm running the stripe/stripe-php 6.43.0 API on Laravel 5.8 and everything works fine until I try to pull a customer's bank account as a source.  Or any source, really.

Here's what I've got:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    $token = \Stripe\Token::create([
        'bank_account' => [
            'country' => $request->country,
            'currency' => $request->currency,
            'account_holder_name' => $request->account_holder_name,
            'account_holder_type' => $request->account_holder_type,
            'routing_number' => $request->routing_number,
            'account_number' => $request->account_number
        ]
    ])->__toArray(true);
    //dd($token);

    $bank_account = \Stripe\Customer::createSource(
        \Auth::user()->company->stripe_id,
        [
            'source' => $token['id'],
        ]
    );
    $bank_array = $bank_account->__toArray(true);
    //dd($bank_array);

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve(\Auth::user()->company->stripe_id);
    //dd($customer);
    $bank_account = $customer->sources()->retrieve(\Auth::user()->company->stripe_bank_id);
    dd($bank_account);
```

Everything works fine until I get to $customer->sources()->retrieve, then it throws a Call to undefined method Stripe\Customer::sources() error.  The company creates in the Stripe dashboard and the bank account is there also.  I've also double and triple checked that the variables for the bank account ID and Stripe ID are being set in the API request.

I've also tried creating the customer & bank account without tokenizing (doesn't make a difference), and I've tried to find a source id so I can just \Stripe\Source::retrieve($src), but the API responses don't contain a source ID.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought, but try removing the parens from sources so it's `$customer->sources->retrieve(....`

Comment: @aynber, unfortunately, that doesn't do anything.  I've also tried getSource and getSources, with and without parenths with no luck.